# How to change the value of an input element generated by a html helper in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trapped in an everlasting loop to find the solution for this problem.

I am generating an advance link using a custom html helper to add new children for a parent object. Here is the html helper I use:

```
public static IHtmlString AddLink<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string linkText, string containerElement, string counterElement, string collectionProperty, Type nestedType, string productId)
        {
            var ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            var nestedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType);
            var partial = htmlHelper.EditorFor(x => nestedObject).ToHtmlString().JsEncode();
            partial = partial.Replace("id=\\\"nestedObject", "id=\\\"" + collectionProperty + "_" + ticks + "_");
            partial = partial.Replace("name=\\\"nestedObject", "name=\\\"" + collectionProperty + "[" + ticks + "]");
            var js = string.Format("javascript:addNestedForm('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');return false;", containerElement, counterElement, ticks, partial);
            TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("a");
            tb.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
            tb.Attributes.Add("onclick", js);
            tb.InnerHtml = linkText;
            var tag = tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag);
        }
```

I use this function using a loop in the view. Shortly, the view code is like this:

```
@Html.AddLink("Add More Part", "#parts", ".part", "Parts", typeof(percobaan2.Models.Part), Convert.ToString(Model.Id))
```

So when the link generated from the code above is clicked, html elements are appended to the parent element. Here are the generated html tags:

```
<input data-val="true" id="Parts_1__Id" name="Parts[1].Id" type="hidden" value="33">
<input data-val="true" id="Parts_1__ProductId" name="Parts[1].ProductId" type="hidden" value="0">
```

And here is what I need:

I need to loop for each input element that is created, to look for the name or id with **ProductId** (in the code above it is the second input element), then after I find it, I need to change its value into the **value** of productId from the html helper parameter (in the code above, the value is 0, and for example I want to make it 22 because the productId parameter in the Html helper is 22).

**UPDATED**

Here is the JS code for **addNestedForm** function:

```
function addNestedForm(container, counter, ticks, content) {
    var nextIndex = $(counter).length;
    var pattern = new RegExp(ticks, "gi");
    content = content.replace(pattern, nextIndex);
    $(container).append(content);
}
```

Comment: Where is your input created? Can you share your _addNestedForm_ code?

Comment: I updated the question. Now with the addNestedForm code.

Comment: @thepirat000 notification

Comment: How are you using `partial` as a variable name when it is a keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: Do you want to change the value pre-Render (server-side) or post-Render (client-side)? I assume post-Render, but I figured I'd ask just to make sure.

Comment: @LászlóKoller Well, either way Sir! If both of them are easy and short, I would be glad if you could write them down here. If it needs more effort for you to write one of them, just give me the easiest for you to write down.

Comment: @ChrisHardie It's my bad! hahaha. It was because I need to change some part of it. Anyway, it works but as you said, I'd better not to do it again. And I wont :D